# How do I add an element to list without adding that element twice in python I have tried this

Tags: python

```
myUniqueList = []

def add_up():
       num = 45,68,95,82,45
       if num not in myUniqueList:
            myUniqueList.append(num)

add_up()
print (myUniqueList)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `num` is a tuple of a few numbers. What is your expected output? What is the actual problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want

```
myUniqueList = []

def add_up():
       num = [45,68,95,82,45]
       for i in num:
           if i not in myUniqueList:
               myUniqueList.append(i)

add_up()
print (myUniqueList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'pythonic' way of doing it is using 'set' rather than a list.
A set is a collection that holds unique values - that means you can store a value only once, and if you try to add it again it will be ignored.
The code using sets becomes much more simple:

```
myUniqueSet = set()

def add_up():
       num = [45,68,95,82,45]
       for i in num:
               myUniqueSet.add(i)
```

In addition, if you already have the items stored in a list and you would like to just remove duplicate elements, all you will need to do is:

```
num = [45,68,95,82,45]
mySet = set(num)
```